# Vue redirect after getting store's values

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

I was trying to make an edit page */edit/:id* where input's value comes from the vuex store, but if the store doesn't have a task with the same id of the params I want to redirect to */404*, how can I achieve this? tried *created()* but it didn't work. Im using Vue3

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "EditTaskForm",
  data() {
    return {
      newTaskDesc: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    const task = this.$store.getters.getTaskById(Number(this.$route.params.id));
    if (!task) this.$router.push("/404");
  },
  mounted() {
    const task = this.$store.getters.getTaskById(Number(this.$route.params.id));
    this.newTaskDesc = task.desc;
  },
  methods: {
    submitEdit() {
      this.$store.dispatch("editTask", {
        newTaskDesc: this.newTaskDesc,
        id: Number(this.$route.params.id),
      });
      this.$router.push("/");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is what route guards are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try follwoing:

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  const task = this.$store.getters.getTaskById(Number(this.$route.params.id));
  if (!task) this.$router.push("/404");
},
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "EditTaskForm",
  data() { ... },
  mounted() { ... },
  methods: { ... },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    const task = this.$store.getters.getTaskById(Number(this.$route.params.id));
    if (!task) this.$router.push("/404");
  }
};
</script>
```

[Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard)